# Covariance with Interface - enumeration of interface

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, covariance

I have a class like this:

```
public partial class GmxGlobalList : DynamicBindingListBase<GmxGlobal>
```

Where `DynamicBindingListBase` implements `Collection<T>` which extends from `IEnumerable<T>` - in this case `IEnumerable<GmxGlobal>`.

The class `GmxGlobal` is defines like

```
public partial class GmxGlobal : IGmxGlobal
```

I want now to declare `GmxGlobalList` like

```
public partial class GmxGlobalList : DynamicBindingListBase<GmxGlobal>, IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal>
```

But this does not work, because I should declare the Method `IEnumerator<IGmxGlobal> GetEnumerator()` - but this is already implemented from `Collection<T>` - but not with `IGmxGlobal` but with `GmxGlobal`. I would ask you, why I have to implement `IEnumerator<IGmxGlobal> GetEnumerator()`? - What sould I do, that I can declare, that GmxGlobalList is an `IEnumerable` or `ICollection` or `IList` of `IGmxGlobal` (or something other where `IGmxGlobal` can be enumerated).

Comment: Isn't enough having DynamicBindingListBase<GmxGlobal> like a base ? Why you need an IEnumerable ?

Comment: GmxGlobalList defines IEnumerable<GmxGlobal>. It does also implement the interface IGmxGlobalList. Now, I want to define this interface (IGmxGlobalList) to implement IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal> because I have to use an object of GmxGlobalList (which I does also know it as IGmxGlobalList) and enumerate it where I also only know IGmxGlobal and not GmxGlobal. For this, I have to declare IGmxGlobalList : IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DynamicBindingListBase<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `GmxGlobalList` inherits from `DynamicBindingListBase<GmxGlobal>` and implements `IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal>`.
`GmxGlobalList` implements both `IEnumerable<GmxGlobal>` and `IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal>`.

I'm going to assume that `DynamicBindingListBase<T>` already has a concrete implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`.  This implementation wouldn't work as a `IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal>` since `IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal>` has a wider scope than `IEnumerable<GmxGlobal>`.

If you were to just have the following:

```
GmxGlobalList : DynamicBindingListBase<GmxGlobal>
```

Due to `IEnumerable` being co-variant, you can already use `GmxGlobalList` as a `IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal>`.  Like this:

```
IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal> foo = new GmxGlobalList();
```

If you really need to implement `IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal>` you can write the implementation details to wrap around `DynamicBindingListBase<GmxGlobal>`.

```
public IEnumerator<IGmxGlobal> GetEnumerator()
{
    return (base as IEnumerator<GmxGlobal>).GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
IEnumerable<IGmxGlobal> e = (IEnumerable<GmxGlobal>)instanceOfGmxGlobalList;
```